# Regex hex character limit

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make a (C#) regular expression that matches codes with a few rules:

1. The accepted characters are hex (and capitalized), (therefore 0-9 A-F): `^[A-F0-9]*$`
2. The number of characters is between 9 and 10: `^[A-F0-9]{9,10}$`
3. The same character cannot appear more than twice consecutively (eg. *AAABCDEF0* not allowed) **?**
4. No more than 5 letters in the code (eg. *A1BC2E3FF4* not allowed) **?**
5. No more than two numbers are equal (eg. *A1BC1E1234* not allowed) **?**
6. No more than three letters are equal (eg. *A1AA1234A5* not allowed) **?**

Keep in mind, that the rules 3-6 can occur anywhere within the sentence, not necessarily the start). If anyone of you can help me with any of the rules between 3 and 6, it will be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Go try yourself and come with a specific problem than giving us your requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does seem to come out of nowhere (homework?)... What's the problem you're trying to solve?

If you want to do it yourself, in order to get you started you should try learning about positive and negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

They're usually a great and easy way to add condition on a string.

For example, this regex will (`(?:...)` is a non capturing group):

```
#^(?=.{9,10}$)(?!(?:.*[A-Z]){6})[A-F0-9]*$

^
(?=.{9,10}$)            # check the regex is 9 or 10 charac long
(?!(?:.*[A-Z]){6})      # check there are no more than 5 letters
[A-F0-9]*$              # actually match the string (not mandatory if you just need to validate)
```

If you want to test it online, regex101 is usually a great website to learn and goof around.

Good luck !

Comment: That does give some indication of where to look. No this is not homework, just something I'm trying to get done :) I'll look around and see what I can find.